# creating the menu for a website for example, a homepage

Tags: html, css

Here, my aim is to create a menu for a home page of my e-library project, this menu must include all the files for those users who wish to select particular functionality which is enclosed by me in the program.

This menu symbol must contain 3 **vertical lines**.

When the user clicks it ,this should pop up the submenu as well.

Please can u suggest me what i am missing out or doing wrong here?

html code:

```
<nav> 
<ul> <li><a href="">Books</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Members</a></li> 
 <li><a href="">Return</a></li>

 </ul> 
 </nav>
```

css styles:

```
li { display: inline-block; display: inline; float: left; } 

ul { background-color: #F2C777; } /*Force the list to expand to contain the links, add some padding around each link, and apply a link text color*/
li a { display: block; padding: 10px; color: #7C785B; } /*Cause the links to change color when hovered on*/
li a:hover { background-color: #EC8C65; } 

ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #F2C777; }
li { display: inline-block; }
li a { display: block; padding: 10px; color: #7C785B; }
li a:hover { background-color: #EC8C65; }
```

Comment: Your chances of getting help without a code are pretty much zero. Give it a try and help will come!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <nav id="navbar"> 
    <a id="navbarLink" href="javascript:void(0)"><i class=""fa fa-bars></i></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Members</a></li> 
      <li><a href="">Return</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </nav>

<script>
$("#navbarLink").click(function(){
  $("#navbar ul").toggleClass("selected");
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And your CSS will be

```
li { display: inline-block; display: inline; float: left; } 

ul { background-color: #F2C777; } /*Force the list to expand to contain the links, add some padding around each link, and apply a link text color*/
li a { display: block; padding: 10px; color: #7C785B; } /*Cause the links to change color when hovered on*/
li a:hover { background-color: #EC8C65; } 

ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #F2C777; display:none; }
li { display: inline-block; }
li a { display: block; padding: 10px; color: #7C785B; }
li a:hover { background-color: #EC8C65; }
.selected { display:block; }
```